# Deleting update data after version 1.0.4 for Super Smash Bros. 3DS

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds, super-smash-bros-4

While I haven't updated Super Smash Bros 3DS since Version 1.0.3, I've been debating updating it to the latest version of 1.0.5.

However, I've heard that version 1.0.4 added an extra update to the game, which is done once you start up the game after the update. I vaguely remember reading about it when it came out, that if you delete the game data then start it up without it being there, your save file you have won't be able to load. If I recall correctly though, you can carry on from this point with a fresh new file.

When you re-update Smash Bros 3DS back to the most recent version, does this give you back your original file that you had before removing the update data or the newer file in its place? I assume the same will be applied to when the DLC is out.

Comment: What do you mean by save file won't be able to load? Are you talking about things like replays won't be able to load? Updating the game does not delete your progress with things like unlocked levels, challenges and characters.

Comment: By save file not loading, I mean that it won't load up due to it not matching the update that happened to the game cartridge (I own the physical version), as in, I delete the e-shop download patch, and when I re-download that patch, the data loaded will be what it was before I removed the patch update data (I have everyone unlocked, all stages and about 87 challenges done). I know updating won't delete any progress I made, though I want to know if my original file will be safe if I delete the update patch after updating to 1.0.5, in the event I want to try and redo various glitches again.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you get the patch data back, it should give you your data back to you.
If the patch data was very important to the game (physical games think like this), it will decide whether you need your data back or not. It will then decide to give your data back.

Answer (score -3):

Yes, you get your original data back. I just did it in version 1.1.2.